# NSView not removing from superview

Tags: cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I have an NSView (we'll call it view1) that is from an NSViewController.  The Super view (which we'll call view2) is located inside an NSWindowController.  The problem is, I can add view1 to view2, but I can't remove it.

Comment: Why not? What have you tried?

Comment: `[class.view removeFromSuperView];` and putting a `removeFromSuperView` in the actual view controller class and calling the method from the windowctrler class

Comment: No, the superview either is located within another view, or is the content view of its window. The NSWindowController is not relevant. What does `[class.view superview]` return after `removeFromSuperview`? How are you adding the view to the superview?

Comment: null.  I'm adding the view by using `[view addSubview:[class.view]];`

Comment: err, make that `[view addSubview:class.view];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment I'd guess one of your instance variables to the view controller or the view itself isn't being set correctly, so you're calling `removeFromSuperView` on nil. Use the debugger to explicitly see the state of the objects involved.

Comment: the view isn't nil before I call `removeFromSuperview` but after I call remove then it is null, but the view itself isn't getting removed

Comment: Matt S.: Check `view` (the superview). It probably is `nil`.